# How to prevent someone from entering strings without making it available for translation?

Tags: plugin-development, translation, localization, parse, xgettext

I am working to make all strings in my plugin ready for translation by putting them under __() or _e() as per requirement. Now in future to avoid others in my team to add strings without making available for translation(bare strings), I want to add a code that runs may be on pushing the code(in my git repository) and throws exception mentioning the bare strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know if string should be translatable or not (should a `'fail'` in a json response be translatable?). Some things just need proper code review and can not be automated.